# Why does Tornado's WSGI support block for more than one request?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, wsgi

Imagine the following tornado app:

```
import logging
import time

from tornado import gen, httpserver, ioloop, web, wsgi


def simple_app(environ, start_response):
    time.sleep(1)
    status = "200 OK"
    response_headers = [("Content-type", "text/plain")]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [b"Hello, WSGI world!\n"]

class HelloHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        yield gen.moment
        self.write('Hello from tornado\n')
        self.finish()

def main():
    wsgi_app = wsgi.WSGIContainer(simple_app)
    tornado_app = web.Application(
        [
            ('/tornado', HelloHandler),
            ('.*', web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
        ],
        debug=True,
    )
    http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    current_loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    current_loop.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now if you run this and try to get `http://localhost:8888/` tornado blocks until the WSGI request is finished (here after one second sleep). This thing I know. But if you send many request one after another then the IOLoop blocks likely forever.

I tried a benchmark like this:

```
$ ab -n 20 -c 2 localhost:8888
```

In a second terminal I tried to get the other url:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8888/tornado
```

I got the response for the non WSGI request not until all other concurrent WSGI requests are finished. This only works if `yield gen.moment` is removed.

Can anybody explain what is going on here and how I can prevent Tornado from blocking all my requests and not only one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado's `WSGIContainer` is not designed for high-traffic use. See the warning in [its docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer):

> WSGI is a synchronous interface, while Tornado’s concurrency model is based on single-threaded asynchronous execution. This means that running a WSGI app with Tornado’s WSGIContainer is less scalable than running the same app in a multi-threaded WSGI server like gunicorn or uwsgi. Use WSGIContainer only when there are benefits to combining Tornado and WSGI in the same process that outweigh the reduced scalability.

In general it's best to run WSGI and Tornado applications in separate processes so the WSGI parts can have a server that is designed for WSGI. `WSGIContainer` should only be used when there are specific reasons to combine them in the same process, and then it should be used with care to avoid blocking the event loop for too long. It's best to do as much as possible in Tornado-native RequestHandlers so coroutines can be used instead of blocking.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have some benefits from combining WSGI and Tornado so I hoped that I could attenuate the blocking problem by using a priority queue later on so that after one blocking WSGI call Tornado runs the IOLoop and everybody has a chance to go inbetween before it is the next blocking WSGI call's turn. But if Tornado does not run the IOLoop as long as there are *any* outstanding WSGI requests this won't work.