# Flask minimalist API + XHR Ajax slow for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, tornado

I really can't understand this situation. I tried as many web server as possible, from embedded one to tornado web server + nginx.

I've monitored my requests and here is the log:

- WARNING:tornado.access:409 PUT /afficheur/article (127.0.0.1) 8.81ms
- WARNING:tornado.access:409 GET /imprimante/tiroir (127.0.0.1) 1.38ms

Response time is pretty good so far. Troubles begin on my browser. Same result with Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

I use a web profiler bar to monitor XHR requests. Here are the results:

- PUT  xhr 409 http://127.0.0.1:5000/afficheur/article 7ms n/a
- GET  xhr 409 http://127.0.0.1:5000/imprimante/tiroir 162ms   n/a

Weird thing is that when using Chrome embedded developer tool for XHR req monitoring, response time is close to server answer time.

Can someone explain to me why imprimante/tiroir took 162ms with simple Ajax request when the server responded 1.38ms after hit.

I'm really confused with this. Something is most definitely happening on browser side, but I don't known what.

*Note#1: I even tried to remove all treatment from server, nothing changed.*

*Note#2: HTTP 409 code is normal here. Same occurs with HTTP 200.*

*Note#3: .ajax request is asynchronous and does not have success handler nor error.*

Thank!

EDIT:

```js
ouvrir_tiroir = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/imprimante/tiroir',
            type: 'GET'
        });
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is data posted to server? What is response from server?

Comment: With /imprimante/tiroir there is no parameters. Simple HTTP/GET. With afficheur/article there's arguments, but my concerns mainly focus on /imprimante/tiroir. 
The server always respond with application/json content. with {message: 'DebugMessage'}.

Comment: Not sure what issue and expected result are?

Comment: The issue is that ajax request ended after 162ms when the server answered within 2ms. 
Can we have a full picture on what is happening on js-ajax side ?

Comment: What is the request and response times that you are expecting and why do you expect a specific time to completions for an asynchronous procedure?

Comment: When I took the url on new tab, alone, Chrome got the ressource in 9.5ms, but when the same request is set with Ajax, it took 160ms. What the heck is happening ? ^^'

Comment: Can you include `javascript` including ajax call at Question?

Comment: I expect a much lower ajax running time because of the high number of request. I run this project on a raspberry pi and it could get messy. ^^

Comment: How is "much lower ajax running time" quantified? Can you reproduce issue at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co? What data are you serving and how frequently are ajax calls made to URLs? Are you trying to stream data to browser?

Comment: Short terms, I want it to correspond to others requests. Why /afficheur/article finished after 9ms but imprimante/tiroir took 160ms. Both api route have very low complexity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145786/discussion-between-ousret-and-guest271314).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Tornado's WSGI support block for more than one request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702776/why-does-tornados-wsgi-support-block-for-more-than-one-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebProfiler bar does not display the XHR time but the surrounding function delay. (Could be multiple XHR requests, the profiler will sum up everything and assign it to the first XHR call). Be careful then.

Problem solved.